# 2 overlayed EditText fields appearing independently

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a problem with my layout of my App. I have 2 Fragments which must be displayed in an Activity. It works fine, but the Layout somehome displays an EditText twice and also behind each other. You can see the hint of the EditText is darker and once I type something in the TextEdit I can see the other EditText independently still visible in the background. Also the TextView and Switch is displayed twice as you can see from the darkness of the appearance:

[image: Screenshot of the glitch]

The Layout files:
**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".QuickSteuerActivity">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/calculation_fragment"
        android:name="de.immozukunft.quicksteuer.CalculationFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settings_overview_fragment"
        android:name="de.immozukunft.quicksteuer.SettingsFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        /> </LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_calculation.xml** (This is where the EditText and Switch etc. is)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_calculation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/turnover"
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/turnover_tax"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/turnover_vattxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/turnover_vattxt"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/turnover_vat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:foregroundGravity="top"
                android:title="@string/industrial_tax"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/costs"
            android:defaultValue="0"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/costs"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="36sp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/costs_vattxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="@string/turnover_vattxt"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/costs_vat"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:title="@string/industrial_tax"
                android:visibility="visible" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btncalculate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/calculate"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_settings_overview.xml** (2.Fragment)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_settings_overview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/current_settings"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/overview_settings"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

I can also provide the Java-files if necessary or any additional files. I just didn't want to bloat the post.

If anybody has got any other additional advices (coding style etc.) please let me know, I am relatively new to Android programming :)

thanks in advance

THE-E

EDIT:

I think I am messing up the layout with the fragment manager. But I am not sure. Because now I see even some PreferenceFragment.

**onCreate()** of the Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //Layout
    manager = getSupportFragmentManager(); //Fragment-Manager

    CalculationFragment calculationFragment = new CalculationFragment(); //create calculation fragment
    SettingsOverviewFragment settingsOverviewFragment = new SettingsOverviewFragment(); //create settings overview fragment

    calculationFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras()); //I don't know what happens here
    settingsOverviewFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras()); //I don't know what happens here either

    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.calculation_fragment, calculationFragment); //add calculation fragment to the fragment transaction
    transaction.add(R.id.settings_overview_fragment, settingsOverviewFragment); //add settings overview fragment to the fragment transaction
    transaction.commit(); //commit the transaction


}
```

Comment: Your `TextView` and `Switch` are duplicated because are duplicated in your layout `fragment_calculation.xml`

Comment: I think you missunderstood my problem. The bottom EditText, TextView and Switch is fine. The Problem is the top one, look at the screenshot and the marking. Or am I missing your point?

Comment: Wow, sorry I misunderstood. It seems that the fragment is added twice at the same position.

Comment: I have looked further into it but can't figure out a porper link where and why the glitch is happening. I have uploaded my Project to gitHub, is it possible to let you see certain files?

Answer (score 1):

Change height and width of both the fragments to wrap_content and see if it works for you ?

Comment: In which files should I change it ? I have been changing at some different locations but with the same result... Also it appears the same way on different devices (virtual and  real device).

Comment: Change in activity_main.xml

Comment: Ok, I think I am getting closer. I Think I am messing up the whole layout using the FragmentManager in the Java-file.

Comment: I got really strange results after changing the width and height. Somehow when I changed to wrap_content my PreferenceFragment, which is not even in the activity, was display right in the middle of the screen. Can you or maybe someone else look into my code? I have uploaded the whole project to GitHub...

Comment: Its set to private: https://github.com/theemaster/
To give you access I would need your username.

Answer (score 0):

I've used `Hint` in the second text and `TEXT` in the first

```
android:hint="@string/turnover_tax"
```

To display the `text` dimly use the `Hint` instead of the Netscape

```
android:hint="Your String"
android:text="Your String"
```

I've used `Hint` in the second text and `TEXT` in the first

```
android:hint="@string/turnover_tax"
```

To display the `text` dimly use the `Hint` instead of the Netscape

```
android:hint="Your String"
android:text="Your String"
```

Using the `Hint` means a tip which must be written in the `EditText`
When you type Netscape in the Netscape `EditText`, the embedded grid will appear in the `EditText` and can be set or changed
But when you write a hint it will disappear once you start typing in the `EditText` that contains it

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. I was adding in the onCreate of the main Activity a Fragment on top of the already set Fragment using the FragmentManager. The Fragment was already set in the layout ( itself, that is why I don't need to use a FragmentManager (*fragment_calculation.xml*).

All I had to do is set the layout of the activity and I was done.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //Layout
}
```

this was my onCreate()-Method.

thanks for your help! :)